# Find text between a Char

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to replace some custom place holders in a text file, the file looks like this:

```
I am %name% the %profession%...
```

(it should be replaced for example with "I am Ronald the Clown")

Right now I am using following regex to replace the place holders:

```
(%.*%)
```

it finds everything between the %-mark:

```
%name%
% the %
%profession%
```

obviously I want to ignore "% the %".. Any idea how to accomplish this? I could do this without regex but maybe there is a way with regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

`%([^ %]+)%`

`[^ %]` will match anything but a space or a percent sign (if you're using variables without spaces as I hope).

**EDIT**: `\b` didn't work, sorry.